# /dev/input file created, but contains no data stream

Tags: linux, usb, linux-mint

So, I'm trying to read a USB device in a brand new installation of Linux Mint.

The way I've done it before is to read the raw stream found in /dev/input/by-id

The device is being detected, and it is producing the expected device:

```
$ ls /dev/input/by-id/
usb-Generic_WebCam_SC-13HDL11939N_200901010001-event-if00
usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00
```

But when I look at the file using

```
tail -f /dev/input/by-id/usb-Generic_WebCam_SC-13HDL11939N_200901010001-event-if00
```

No data is output to the terminal when I press some keys. I've tried it with sudo, I've tried changing the rights for the file. It basically waits where it is, unchanged.

There's a lot of questions about devices not appearing, or about IO errors when reading a file, but I can't find anyone else who's had the same problem.

Why might Linux Mint be detecting the device, but not reading the data from it?

---

Additional requested information:

```
# ls -lRa /dev/input/by-id
/dev/input/by-id:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Jul  2 21:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 360 Jul  2 21:38 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Jul  2 21:24 usb-Generic_WebCam_SC-13HDL11939N_200901010001-event-if00 -> ../event9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul  2 21:38 usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00 -> ../event10
```

I tried tail -f on /dev/input/event10, too. Same result.

Also, the last few lines of dmesg

```
[  263.440421] usb 2-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  263.538270] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0002
[  263.538280] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  263.538285] usb 2-1.1: Product: Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1
[  263.538290] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  263.585640] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[  263.597332] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[  263.597338] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[  263.615420] input: Logitech Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:054C:0002.0001/input/input11
[  263.668811] sony 0003:054C:0002.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Logitech Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
[  811.582183] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  813.318275] usb 2-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  813.416196] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0002
[  813.416207] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[  813.416213] usb 2-1.1: Product: Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1
[  813.416218] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  813.422041] input: Logitech Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:054C:0002.0002/input/input12
[  813.422335] sony 0003:054C:0002.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Logitech Logitech Buzz(tm) Controller V1] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
```

---

I have found that it can be read using the evtest utility (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection/evtest), but only as root, or using sudo.

Also as root or sudo, I am unable to see any data in the path mentioned above.

---

P.S. I am able to push control data to the lamps in these controllers via /sys/class/leds/

Comment: Please show us the **unedited** output of `ls -lRa /dev/input/by-id` ?

Comment: Also the **unedited** output of `dmesg | tail -20`, immediately after plugging in the device.

Comment: @zwol I've added information as requested.

Comment: OK, now I need to see `ls -l /dev/input/event[0-9]*`.

Comment: @zwol The event* things range from 0 to 10. I've found a solution, but it's a thoroughly unexpected one, `tail -f` isn't working, but `cat` shows the data as expected. :s ---- I haven't found out why that is.

Comment: Remember how I kept banging on about wanting to see **unedited** output? `ls -l /dev/input/event[0-9]*` provides more information than just the number of event devices that exist.  It is difficult to explain exactly which bits of that additional information are relevant, which is why I asked for all of it.

Comment: If `tail -f ...` doesn't work but `cat ...` does, comparing `strace cat ...` to `strace tail -f ...` may be enlightening.  (Both of these commands will produce a tremendous amount of output, of which only the last couple dozen lines are relevant.)  (I have a hypothesis now, but I want to see `strace tail -f` and the previously requested `ls -l` before I tell you what it is.)

Comment: @zwol It's tricky sharing large outputs piece-meal on a SO question. I've output them to a gist: https://gist.github.com/AJFaraday/433ce596785f7deec1fc6b835dbbd6e3 oddly, with strace, the buttons have an effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with the `tail` program, not with the input devices themselves.  `tail` is trying to read data until "the end of the file" before it starts printing anything -- but an input device *has* no "end of the file", so it will never print anything.  `cat`, on the other hand, writes out data immediately as it comes in, so that works correctly.  I don't know why `tail` worked for you with other input devices in the past.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this is turning into a more complicated issue than I had formerly realised.

Comment: My real problem (probably symptomatic of this) is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165055/reading-usb-input-stream-from-ruby