# Reading USB input stream from ruby.

Tags: ruby, hid, data-stream

Just a bit of background, I'm working with a raw data stream in Linux Mint (32 bit). It's from my library [ruby-buzz](https://github.com/AJFaraday/ruby-buzz), which reads 24-bit lumps out of the data stream file.

I've just re-installed my laptop with Linux Mint, 32-bit, and suddenly I'm seeing the error `Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_fread`.

```
ajfaraday@squishy ~ $ sudo chmod 777 /dev/input/by-id/*
ajfaraday@squishy ~ $ irb
2.2.1 :001 > path = '/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00'
 => "/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00" 
2.2.1 :002 > f = File.open(path)
 => #<File:/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00> 
2.2.1 :003 > f.read(24)
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_fread - /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_Logitech_Buzz_tm__Controller_V1-event-if00
    from (irb):3:in `read'
    from (irb):3
    from /home/ajfaraday/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.1 :004 > f.read(32)
 => "\xAB>xW\x0E\xDC\x00\x00\x01\x00\xC0\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\xAB>xW\x0E\xDC\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
```

---

On the same system, with the same input device, I saw the issue in [/dev/input file created, but contains no data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164268/dev-input-file-created-but-contains-no-data-stream/38164595)

I don't know why I've previously been fine to use `tail -f` to watch a raw data stream from the terminal, and why I've previously been able to use `file.read(24)` to grab that 24 bit chunk from ruby. Including on an install of Mint. But now I'm unable to do either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the solution I found, but it will probably help anyone faced with the same problem, so here goes.

It appears to be a consequence of the 32-bit architecture of Linux Mint that it will not allow the `file.read` method to work with an argument that's not a power of 2 (e.g. 8, 16, 32). I do not know why this is.

However, re-installing using the 64-bit version of Mint, this works as I was previously seeing on my KDE install (which, in retrospect, was probably a 64-bit architecture).